# Passing different objects to a function

Tags: c++, object

I have a header file (here simplified) with the following code:

```
class mark1
{
 public:
    double   ID;
};

class remap
{
public:
    void tstfunc(mark1& M);
};
```

And in the corresponding cpp-file I have a simple function, such as:

```
void tstfunc(mark1& M)
{        
    cout << M.ID << endl;
}
```

In the main function, I'll execute tstfunc ...

Now I had to add a second class to the header, for example:

```
class mark2
{
 public:
    double   ID;
};
```

How do I have to rewrite tstfunc that I can execute the function in the main-funcition with both classes?

In the end, I would like to do something like that:

```
...
int main
{
    M1 mark1;
    M2 mark2;

    tstfnc(mark1)
    tstfnc(mark2)

    ...
}
```

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Your `tstfunc` has a reference that doesn't refer to anything. That shouldn't compile. Better post some more realistic code.

Comment: I'm troubled by `tstfunct()` which is declared as member in `class remap`, but is not defined, and the self-standing `tstfunct()` which is defined without arguments, and that you call with an argument.  There's something missing here.

Comment: I am very worried about a `double` being used as `ID`. You do know floating point numbers can have troubling behavior on equality/ordering ? If it's an integer, you may use `int64_t` or `uint64_t` and otherwise a `std::string` allows you to treat IDs as opaque byte sequences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If both mark classes have no common base class, you can use the power of template programming:

```
template<typename T> void tstfunc(const T& M)
{
    cout << M.ID << endl;
}
```

Comment: Will this work? How does the compiler know that you will only give it `T`s that have an `ID` field?

Comment: Would it be a better practice to use an interface ? (for my own knowledge)

Comment: @Jashaszun If you give it anything else, the compiler will tell you so.

Comment: @EoiFirst That depends. If they already had a common base class with an ID field, I'd opt for using that. As they don't, I would not create one just for this case.